# How to use .NET System.Web.Caching IIS (Machine) wide?

Tags: asp.net, iis, caching

Is here a way to share System.Web.Caching between IIS applications?

The simple goal is: share cache in whole box, and can be read/write from any websites on IIS

Is this possible by default System.Web.Caching, or is here any third party application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Web.Caching is an in-memory cache that cannot be shared. You will need to use a distributed cache like [Velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx), [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/), [memcached](http://memcached.enyim.com/).

Comment: thats most like for multiple machines or farm. My require is on same machine, from different IIS applications

Comment: @EricYin, you still need a distributed cache if you want to share between applications on the same machine as they are different processes. An in-memory cache is stored (as its name suggests) in the memory of the current application to which for obvious reasons other applications do not have access.

Comment: Is there some matured application that host in memory and answer calls from different process that works as a cache in a same machine?

Comment: @EricYin, I don't understand your question. You are asking which distributed cache to use?

Comment: I found another thread answer my question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488478/sharing-cache-between-apps-asp-net-on-the-same-physical-machine